# Custom Site Collection Health Rule

Tags: 2013, health

SP13 provides Site Collection Level health rules which are mostly geared towards helping with Upgrade.

Are these rules extensible? Can I create my own rule?

For example, if I have developed a custom application in SharePoint, I may want to check the health of the custom application by checking if right features are activated, custom lists that I created exist, right features are activated, custom settings that I stored for the application exists or not.. so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

these are extensible rule...you can add your custom code in it.
[Bring your SharePoint farm governance to the next level – writing custom Health Analyzer Rule for SharePoint](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/bring-your-sharepoint-farm-governance-to-the-next-level-writing)

[here is MSDN link but it is for 2010, will give you helpful information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538249%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for response. These are farm level health rules introduced in SharePoint 2010. SP13 has site collection level rules and each rule has GUID which can be run separately from PowerShell, are you aware of any extensibility there?